# Рекурсивный перебор комбинаций без повторения состовляющих

Tags: php, рекурсия

Написал следующий алгоритм

```
    private $arr_num;
    private $count;
    private $three;

    public function test_tot() {

    $this->arr_num = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    $this->count = 0;
    $this->three = [];

    $this->threeonthree($this->arr_num);

    return $this->count;

    }

    public function threeonthree($arr) {

    if (count($this->three) == 9) {

        $this->count++;

        $this->three = [];

        return;

    }

    $tmp = $arr;

    foreach ($tmp as $key => $val) {

        unset($arr[$key]);
        sort($arr);

        array_push($this->three, $val);

        if($this->iter > 10) return;

        $this->threeonthree($arr);

        $arr = $tmp;

    }

}
```

И ведет она себя не ожидаемо, не могу понять почему

Как ведет:

Символы повторяются

И такое чувство что он пропускает вызов, что то не так с условием?

Что хотел сделать:

Первый проход

Вызываемый метод оставляет у себя копию целого полученного массива, берет первый элемент вырезает его и передает методу урезанный массив и так вот он урезается пока не закончится.

Второй проход

Потом метод восстанавливает урезанный массив своей копией, берет второй элемент, вырезает из восстановленного массива второй элемент передает его дальше и тд

Comment: а как ведет, а как будет ожидаемо? добавьте данных то тестовых

Comment: @teran добавил описание ожидаемого поведения

Answer (score 1):

раз уж написал код, то оставлю тут. обычно генерация перестановок без повторений в лексикографическом порядке выглядит как то так

```
class Perms {

    private $n;
    private $used;
    private $data;
    private $items;

    public function __construct($n, $items = null) {
        $this->n = $n;
        $this->used = array_fill(0, $n, false);
        $this->data = $this->used;

        $this->items = $items ? $items : range(1, $n);
    }


    public function lex($pos = 0) {

        if ($pos == $this->n) {
            $this->out();
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->n; $i++) {
            if (!$this->used[$i]) {
                $this->used[$i] = true;
                $this->data[$pos] = $this->items[$i];

                $this->lex($pos + 1);
                $this->used[$i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function out(){
        echo implode(' ', $this->data) . "\n";
    }

}

(new Perms(3))->lex();
(new Perms(3, ['a','b','c'])->lex();
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибки в своем алгоритме, основная в обнулении массива

```
    public function threeonthree($arr) {

    if (count($this->three) == 9) {

        if($l1 == $n1 && $l2 == $n2 && $l3 == $n3) {

            $this->count++;

        }

        array_splice($this->three, -1);

        return;

    }

    $tmp = $arr;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {

        unset($tmp[$key]);
        sort($tmp);

        array_push($this->three, $val);

        $this->threeonthree($tmp);

        $tmp = $arr;

    }

    array_splice($this->three, -1);

}
```